# Counter inside xsl:for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt, loops

How to get a counter inside xsl:for-each loop that would reflect the number of current element processed.
For example my source XML is

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title>The Unbearable Lightness of Being </title>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Narcissus and Goldmund</title>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Choke</title>
    </book>
</books>
```

What I want to get is:

```
<newBooks>
    <newBook>
        <countNo>1</countNo>
        <title>The Unbearable Lightness of Being </title>
    </newBook>
    <newBook>
        <countNo>2</countNo>
        <title>Narcissus and Goldmund</title>
    </newBook>
    <newBook>
        <countNo>3</countNo>
        <title>Choke</title>
    </newBook>
</newBooks>
```

The XSLT to modify:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <newBooks>
            <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
                <newBook>
                    <countNo>???</countNo>
                    <title>
                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                    </title>
                </newBook>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </newBooks>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the question is what to put in place of ???. Is there any standard keyword or do I simply must declare a variable and increment it inside the loop?

As the question is pretty long I should probably expect one line or one word answer :)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

`position()`. E.G.:

```
<countNo><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></countNo>
```

Comment: This is all fine and dandy until you have to add a filter like xsl:if inside your xsl:for-each. Then position() is USELESS and you need proper counter.

Comment: @Mike Stavrov That was not part of the question! Cannot cover every situation

Comment: @redsquare Correct. Just adding my two cents. I had to write an XSL extension function to resolve my described situation. Maybe I should ask people here about better solutions.

Comment: @MikeStarov then how to do if there is a `xsl:if` inside the `xsl:for-each`? What is a "proper counter"? Can you point to some resource?

Comment: @lajarre You write a custom extension function to be called from XSL. You can also do two pass processing. Process once and save to xsl:variable. Then apply templates on xsl variable contents and add numbering using position()

Answer (score 13):

Try inserting `<xsl:number format="1. "/><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>` in the place of ???.

Note the "1. " - this is the number format. More info: [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/11/06/tr.html)

Comment: Thanks, that is an interesting read as well.I  will probably use that approach when some formatting is required

Comment: XSLT 1.0 version: `<xsl:number format="1. " value="position()"/>`

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1" />
```

**Edit** - had a brain freeze there, position() is more straightforward!

Comment: Still could be useful, especially if you're selecting based on criteria other than position(). +1

Answer (score 8):

You can also run conditional statements on the Postion() which can be really helpful in many scenarios.

for eg.

```
 <xsl:if test="(position( )) = 1">
     //Show header only once
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: This fails if you have a filter such as a xsl:sort because then the first item may not be the first to be processed.

Answer (score 5):

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <newBooks>
                <xsl:for-each select="books/book">
                        <newBook>
                                <countNo><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></countNo>
                                <title>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                                </title>
                        </newBook>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </newBooks>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```