# xslt assign value to tag of div html assign variable

Tags: jquery, html, xml, xslt

I have xslt which uses an image to get displayed in slider of jquery I have this code...

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class=""><img src="images/20.jpg"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class="active"><img src="images/20.jpg"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""><img src="images/20.jpg"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3" class=""><img src="images/20.jpg"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4" class=""><img src="images/20.jpg"></li>
          </ol>
          </div>
```

which works fine but what I want I want this (data-slide-to="4") to get dynamic in xslt what I tried this

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <xsl:for-each select="ResponseDetails/SearchItemInformationResponse/ItemDetails/ItemDetail/HotelInformation/Links/ImageLinks/ImageLink">

                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="Position()" class="">
                      <img src="{Image}"/>
                    </li>

                  </xsl:for-each>
                </ol>
</div>
```

but in this case position of loop do not works.... data-slide-to="Position()" it should be replaced with what?? I also tried this     `<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>` but it didnt work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counter inside xsl:for-each loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93511/counter-inside-xslfor-each-loop)

Comment: data-slide-to="<countNo><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></countNo>" its not working

Comment: I think it should be `<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to='<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>'><img src="{Image}"/></li>`.

Comment: No its not working invalid it gives me this error '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 119, position 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Attribute Value Templates when you are writing out attributes in the result tree

```
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{position() - 1}" class="">
```

(Note that `position()` starts at 1, not 0, hence the `position() - 1`)

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally. This is the same syntax to output the **src** attribute on the **img** element.