# How to automatically assign value to an attribute using XSLT in for-each loop?

Tags: xslt

In a for-each XSLT loop I construct an HTML structure of the form:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading001">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible in that loop to generate the suffix of the attributes `id` and assign to it? So that in first loop the `ID`s become "*accordion1*" and "*heading001*", in the second loop become "*accordion2*" and "*heading002*", etc? And if so, can you provide an example?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create nodes/attributes with values in sequence iterating on some nodes

Comment: This question has already been answered here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93511/counter-inside-xslfor-each-loop

Comment: @Leander Conradie need the same as your link shows but for attribute values... Not element values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your for each loop, example for the id do something like below

```
<xsl:attribute name="id">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('accordion', position()"  />
 </xsl:attribute>
```